# Boxing+Varargs is preferred over Boxing+Widening

Tags: java, overloading

Please correct me if I'm wrong. 
Is Boxing+Varargs is preferred over Boxing+Widening?

I found in a [site](http://studiofreya.com/blog/java/java-conversions-and-golden-rules-of-widening-boxing-varargs/) that its the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What method is called when several could qualify is defined in the [JLS #15.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.
>
> The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

So in summary: widening > boxing&unboxing > varargs

Answer (score 0):

Boxing+Widening is preferred over Boxing+Varargs. A simple test would confirm the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 2;
    doX(2);
}

static void doX(Object i){
    System.out.println("object...");
}
static void doX(Integer... i){
    System.out.println("int...");
}
```

Prints:

```
object...
```

EDIT: Sorry, my bad. I have corrected the code. Didn't notice I had typed "Object..."

Answer (score 0):

`Boxing + Widening` is preferred over `Boxing + Varargs`. I have changed @John's example to show this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 2;
    doX(i);
}

static void doX(Object i) {
    System.out.println("Object");
}

static void doX(Integer... i) {
    System.out.println("Integer...");
}
```

prints

```
Object
```

Comment: There is no widening in your example. Your example shows that boxing is preferred over varargs.

Comment: @assylias: Isn't `Integer -> Object` considered widening according to [this part of the specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)?

Comment: Yes you are right, for some reason I had primitive widening, not reference widening, in mind.